# How to add a character in a string after each vowel using python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

I'm trying to write a program that takes in a string(sentence) and after each vowel it adds a letter for example: "Jon" becomes "Jofon". I thought doing it with for loops maybe(certainly) there is a better way.
Here it's what I tried so far:

```
sen="Jon"
newString=""


for letter in sen:
    if letter == "a" or letter == "e" or letter == "i" or letter == "o" \ 
    or letter == "u" or letter == "y":
        newString+=letter+"f"+letter


print(newString)
```

It seems to add the letter "f" only to vowels leaving consonants out giving me this result:

```
 ofo
```

Comment: You might want to consider using an `else:` clause on your `if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, since there's no fallback for when it's not a vowel... You need an `else`:

```
for letter in sen:
    if letter in "aeiouy":
        newString+=letter+"f"+letter
    else:
        newString+=letter
```

(doesn't handle the case where the letters are uppercased BTW)

But there are more efficient (and pythonic ways) of doing it. Concatenating strings is underperformant, and this kind of problem is better solved using comprehensions or regular expressions.

In one line, using ternary and list comprehension, passed to `"".join`:

```
newstring = "".join(["{0}f{0}".format(letter) if letter.lower() in "aeiouy" else letter for letter in sen])
```

Alternative with regular expressions, capturing the vowel as a group and using it twice to wrap the `f` char against recalled group (`\1`) using raw prefix or `\1` is interpreted as ASCII character `\x01` instead:

```
re.sub("([aeiouy])",r"\1f\1","Jon",flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

that finds a vowel, and replaces it by this vowel + `f` + this vowel again.

Comment: @L.B yes, it is possible, but not the best option as explained.

Comment: I'm a beginner in python, started a week ago, i'm trying not to rely too much in build-in functions at the beginning, but could i ask you to explain to me or a link to understand the regular expression part, what are the flags , r, 1f\. Thanks!

Comment: I've edited the regex part. but if you don't understand that, skip it. the above approach is OK.